# Summing specific cells in excel with header that meets specific text criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a specific problem like following:

[image]

As you can see I have 3 cells in which I have "Total" value of something.

I'd like to sum all of these values below, in whichever column there's a text that matches the word "Total".

So for instance there are 3 columns that contain word "Total" right now, and I'd like to sum their values below them which are:

```
1500, 11223 and 11220
```

I've tried using the sumif function in Excel, but for some reason it seems to be able only to sum a range of columns, not range of multiple rows...

I tried this:

```
=SUMIF(A2:AJ2,"*Total*",B3:AJ3)

B3:AJ3 are colums right below these upper ones...
```

Edit: The total value that I should get is 23943

Comment: Why not just use the column letters? Otherwise you'll need an index/match type thing. e.g. `$N1=$D1+$G1+$L1`

Comment: You mean like T and stuff like that? But there's another problem regarding the summing thingy... The sumif function for some reason isn't able to sum multiple rows, only 1 column within a given specific range...

Comment: Are you summing per row or for the total? Why not use subtotals then?

Comment: Hi @Raystafarian because I want the process to be automated whenever I put a new cell with text of "Total", I want it to be automatically summed for the given range ...

Comment: New cell per row or insert a new column?

Comment: Insert a new column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46692/discussion-between-perkes456-and-raystafarian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, not nearly as complicated as I was thinking

```
=SUMIF(A1:G1,"*total*",A2:G2)
```

Capitalization differences would need something like

```
=SUMIF(UPPER(A1:G1),"*TOTAL*",A2:G2)
```

Comment: I tried using this, and it wasn't this one ...I found a solution by using the sumproduct function

Comment: Make sure you adjust it for your range. If your capitalization is different across columns, you should use the `UPPER` to get the matches.

Comment: This is it. Ty !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{=sum(index(whole grid,,match("*total*", headers,0)))}
```

You can sum entire rows/columns if you use index and one match function. You cannot index/match both row and column because then it will just take the first one of each.